# How to fix this database sort problem for latest result

Tags: java, sql

I need to retrieve the latest data from database.
I stored date as long. It works as long as I retrieve and format date on Java side.

But if I format the date from database and retrieve then all date/time are same like 30/01/2020.

So I am not getting the accurate result.

Here is my Query I tried so far

```
Select * 
from (select 
  Id,
  (CASE when TransactionId<10 THEN 'CR-0'||TransactionId ELSE 'CR-'||TransactionId End) as TransactionId,
  Description,
  case when Date=-1 THEN '' else strftime('%d/%m/%Y', Date / 1000, 'unixepoch') End as Date,
  printf('%.2f', Amount) AS Amount,
  'Credit' as Type from income_agent WHERE AgentId=1 union all select Id, 
  (CASE when TransactionId<10 THEN 'DE-0'||TransactionId ELSE 'DE-'||TransactionId End) as TransactionId,
  Description,
  case when Date=-1 THEN '' else strftime('%d/%m/%Y', Date / 1000, 'unixepoch') End as Date,
  printf('%.2f', Amount) AS Amount,
  'Debit' as Type 
  from expense_agent WHERE AgentId=1 
  union all select 
    Id,
    (CASE when TransactionId<10 THEN 'RT-0'||TransactionId ELSE 'RT-'||TransactionId End) as TransactionId,
    Description,case when Date=-1 THEN '' else strftime('%d/%m/%Y', Date / 1000, 'unixepoch') End as Date,
    printf('%.2f', Amount) AS Amount,
    'Return' as Type from return_agent  WHERE AgentId=1
)a 
order by Date Desc 
Limit 0,1
```

The query works If I don't format the date where selecting the result.

Comment: Please tag the database that you are using.

Comment: You should use date='-1' in case statement as strftime returns string value.

Comment: Try providing a minimal reproducible example, many of selected columns aren't related to your issue. Additionaly, there is now way to understand how it works "on Java side" since we cannot see any code (are there any type conversions, when u store the data in Java befroe selecting, etc.)

Comment: Use a comparable format like: `strftime('%Y/%m/%d', Date / 1000, 'unixepoch')`

Answer (score 0):

Include the original date in the subqueries:

```
select . . .
from (select id, date as orig_date, . . .
      . . .
     ) t
order by orig_date;
```

Then, don't select it in the outer query.

Or, just keep the date in the subquery and do the formatting in the outer query.